# Greasemonkey script to find rows with certain conditions

Tags: image, replace, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I tried some different ways do find rows in a table where a columns contain a particular link.

My goal: replace an icon when a link to xyz is in this same row as the image.

This is my snippet so far:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {     
        var links = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(var k = links.length - k; k >= 0; k--) {
            if (links[k].href =="http://www.XXXX.net/forum/index.php?showforum=121"){
                var images = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
                    for (var j=0;j<images.length;j++) {
                    images[j].src = "http://www.XXXX.net/forum/folder_post_icons/icon7.gif";
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is not really the best concept. But as you might see I try to search links in all rows and once the link to forum "121" is found, I try to replace all images in this particular row.

What I get is every image at the site getting replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's simple enough, here's a complete script that does that.
It uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and here's [a handy jQuery reference](http://www.jqapi.com/).  See, especially, the *Selectors* section (which are almost the same as CSS Selectors).

Re: `"What I get is every image at the site getting replaced."` ...

This maybe because the search criteria is too broad.  If it's a poorly designed (uses table layouts) page, every image may be in a table row with a target link!

When posting Greasemonkey questions, **link to the target page**, or at the very minimum, post enough of the page's HTML that we can adjust the GM script to match.

---

Anyway, this will work, possibly pending more information about the target page:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Replace image on custom-targeted row
// @include  http://www.XXXX.net/forum/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//--- This may need tuning based on information not provided!
var targetLinks = $("tr a[href*='showforum=121']");

//--- Loop through the links and rewrite images that are in the same row.
targetLinks.each ( function () {
    //--- This next assumes that the link is a direct child of tr > td.
    var thisRow = $(this).parent ().parent ();

    //--- This may need tuning based on information not provided!
    var images  = thisRow.find ("td img");

    //--- Replace all target images in the current row.
    images.each ( function () {
        $(this).attr (  
            'src', 
            'http://www.XXXX.net/forum/folder_post_icons/icon7.gif'
        );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks, the Forum section I made it for is hidden but next time I try to give some  further details about the site. I had to extend the code a bit :)