# Use Greasemonkey to change row format based on one cell's contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, greasemonkey

I have a table full of cells that look like this:

```
<tr class="dataRow odd">
    <td class="actionColumn"> someAction </td>
    <th class=" dataCell  booleanColumn" scope="row">
        <img class="checkImg" width="21" height="16" title="Not Checked" 
            alt="Not Checked" src="/img/checkbox_unchecked.gif">
        </img>
    </th>
    <td class=" dataCell  "> SomeData </td>
</tr>
```

The middle `<th>` cell will have an image with either `title="Not Checked"` or `title="Checked"`.

I'd like to apply some formatting to the entire row if `title="Not Checked"`. But, I'm new to Greasemonkey and javascript and CSS.

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098115/greasemonkey-script-to-find-rows-with-certain-conditions) but I'm not entirely sure how to adapt it. This seems close, but it's not quite right and I'm not entirely certain how to simply change the FG/BG colors of the row.

```
var targetLinks = $("tr *dataRow*");

//--- Loop through the links and rewrite images that are in the same row.
targetLinks.each ( function () {
  //--- This next assumes that the link is a direct child of tr > td.
  var thisRow = $(this).parent ().parent ();

  //--- This may need tuning based on information not provided!
  var image  = thisRow.find ("img");

  //--- Replace all target images in the current row.
  if ("Not Checked" == image.attr ('title')) {
      //Apply Some formatting to thisRow   
    } 
  );
}
```

Pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This one's a little easier than the linked example, I think.
The key is understanding [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and then using jQuery's `.css()` function.

Assuming the page doesn't use AJAX, here's **a complete script** that works on the HTML you provided:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Format the "not checked" rows
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
//--- The 'Not Checked' is case-sensitive
var notChkdRows = $(
    "tr.dataRow:has(th.booleanColumn img[title='Not Checked'])"
);

//--- Use whatever CSS you wish
notChkdRows.css ( {
    "background":   "lime",
    "font-size":    "3ex"
} );

//--- But some styles do not effect rows, must use on cells
notChkdRows.children ("td,th").css ( {
    "border":       "5px solid pink"
} );
```

---

## You can play with [a live demo of the code at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FsCYU/).