# Use Greasemonkey to change html table cell format based on its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, greasemonkey

I'm way out of my depth with a greasemonkey script. I'm dealing with an html table where the second column has month data in, e.g. 'April', or 'May'. Here's a simplified version of the html I'm dealing with:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table class="gridtable">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="header"></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>blah</td>
                        <td>April</td>
                        <td>blah</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>blah</td>
                        <td>May</td>
                        <td>blah</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

For all rows where the 2nd column/TD contains 'May', I want to use greasemonkey to change the formatting of that cell, e.g. to bold red text, with a yellow background. Here's the code I have so far, but it's not having any effect, and I'm not sure if it's a good starting point (I've only included background color for now, walk before run):

```
var thetds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var j = 0; j < thetds.length; j++) {
if (thetds[j].innerHTML == "May") 
    thetds[j].style.backgroundColor = rgb(250, 220, 0);
}
```

Effectively I want the td to turn from:

```
<td>May</td>
```

to:

```
<td style="background-color: rgb(250, 220, 0); color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;">May</td>
```

Any advice greatly appreciated! Thank you. PS I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906556/use-greasemonkey-to-change-row-format-based-on-one-cells-contents) similar question but I can't flex it to my situation, it is quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rgb(250, 220, 0)` should be `"rgb(250, 220, 0)"`

```
thetds[j].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250, 220, 0)";
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/wsqq7wfz/)

Comment: Ah thank you for the fix, and for the demo, glad to see I was closer than I thought, although... this still isn't working via Greasemonkey... Bit lost.

Comment: @David i tested and it works.here is example greasemonkey script http://pastebin.com/7bvvYwXJ . install it and visit this page https://fiddle.jshell.net/wsqq7wfz/3/show/light/

Comment: Probably doesn't work on OP's page for several reasons: (1) AJAX, (2) whitespace (`.innerHTML == ` is almost always brittle on real-life pages), (3) OP's table-cell search may potentially yield false positives -- once the other issues are sorted (Not checking against structure).

Comment: My web programming isn't strong and I don't know if AJAX is used here, but there's definitely some JavaScript operations going on. It assembles the results, rendering one complete page of HTML. :-S

Comment: @David did you test the example script and page i gave to you?

Comment: I did, the page doesn't load for me in Firefox (on multiple machines). But it loads in Chrome, and loading your script via Tampermonkey works. I'll mark your answer as accepted - obviously the code is right, it just doesn't work on my dynamic page, but I can't really ask for help if I can't describe how the page works. Thanks very much for your solution, I will try to investigate further.